# jQuery - String variable being escaped?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fairly simple script designed to hide/unhide various form fields based on customer type. The code looks as follows:

```
var customerTypeFields = [];
    customerTypeFields['Individual'] = ['First Name(s)', 'Last Name', 'Date of Birth'];
    customerTypeFields['Limited Company'] = ['Name', 'Company Number'];
    customerTypeFields['Partnership'] = ['Name', 'Company Number'];

    $('#customer-type-selector').chosen().change( function() {
        var visibleFields = customerTypeFields[$(this).children("option[value='" + $(this).attr('value') + "']").text()];
        console.log(visibleFields);
        $.each(visibleFields, function(i, field) {
            $('#customer-features').find('input[data-feature-type=' + field + ']').parent().parent().show();
        });
    });
```

This appears to work to some extent, but I'm getting a strange error when loading an individual, which is:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[data-feature-type=First (s)]
```

You will note that `First  (s)` is not in my array, and as such it seems like the word `Name` is being stripped - any idea why the string would be edited like that?

Thanks!

Comment: Try including it inside a quotes,

    `$('#customer-features')
            .find('input[data-feature-type="' + field + '"]')
            .parent().parent().show();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape with double quotes:

```
(...)  .find('input[data-feature-type="' + field + '"]')  (...)
```

See more on [jQuery's Attribute Equals Selector page](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). It basically defines it as:

> `jQuery('[attribute="value"]')`